# How to prevent rendering a new state of an useReducer hook each time?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

There is a problem with useReducer in React. As I change the inputs value, there is a new render of state in useReducer. How can I render the same state of the useReducer?

**officeReducer:**

```
export const INITIAL_STATE = {
    name: "",
    surname: "",
};

const ACTIONS = {
    CHANGE_INPUT: "CHANGE_INPUT",
}

export const officeReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case ACTIONS.CHANGE_INPUT:
          return {
              ...state,
              [action.payload.name]:action.payload.value
          }
      default: {
          return state
      }
  }
}
```

**InputType.js:**

```
import {useReducer, useState} from "react";
import {officeReducer, INITIAL_STATE} from "../../functions/officeReducer";

export const InputType = (props) => {
    const [text, setText] = useState()
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(officeReducer, INITIAL_STATE)

    function handleChange(e) {
      dispatch({ type: "CHANGE_INPUT", payload: {name: e.target.name, value: e.target.value}})
    }

    console.log(state) **//FOR EXAMPLE, AS WE TYPE SMTH IN NAME INPUT THERE IS AN OBJ IN CONSOLE: {name: "MIKE", surname: ""}, THEN WE TYPE INTO A SURNAME INPUT AND WE GET {name: "", surname: "JORDAN"}. The question is: why don't we get {name: "MIKE", surname: "JORDAN"}?**

    return (
      <div className={styles.inputBox}>
        <input id={props.id} type={props.type} required={props.required} name={props.name} onChange={handleChange}/>
        <label htmlFor={props.id} className={text && styles.inputFilled}>{props.placeholder}</label>
      </div>
    )
}
```

**Office.js:**

```
const Office = () => {
return (
    <div className={styles.dataBox}>
      <div className={styles.dataInputs}>
        <InputType placeholder={'Surname'} name={'surname'} required={true} type={'text'}/>
        <InputType placeholder={'Name'} name={'name'} required={true} type={'text'}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Have tried to move `useReducer` to Office component. It works well, but there is a redundant render of Office component.

Comment: Is there anything wrong other than the number of renders?

Comment: @AdamJenkins, actually I get the wrong output at the console as I console.log(state). Sorry for the uppercase letters in advance. There is an example below:

FOR EXAMPLE, AS WE TYPE SMTH IN NAME INPUT THERE IS AN OBJ IN CONSOLE: {name: "MIKE", surname: ""}, THEN WE TYPE INTO A SURNAME INPUT AND WE GET {name: "", surname: "JORDAN"}. The question is: why don't we get {name: "MIKE", surname: "JORDAN"}?

Comment: Ah, I see it now. It’s because your state is the wrong spot. Lift your state (useReducer) up into your Office component and out of your InputType

Comment: @AdamJenkins, okay I got you! Is there any way to prevent rerendering of the Office component?

Comment: Why do you want to prevent rendering of the office component? It's a very important question because under all but the most performance strict circumstances, the number of times a component renders shouldn't really matter to you. Alternatively, rather than discussing minute details like number of renders, what are you trying to do at a high level? Your components are uncontrolled, do you actually need to maintain their state at all or do you just need their values onSubmit?

Comment: @AdamJenkins, I want to prevent rendering of the office component due to the optimization of my app. I think that there is no need to rerender the whole component with inputs, when we have a change in each input at a time. As for your question about what I actually need, I have to store the data from all the inputs I have in office component to store it in database. To be honest, there are more than two inputs. I have put 2 inputs in the question just for the ease of understanding the problem

Comment: Are you noticing a performance problem right now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forms are one of the few areas in react where you should be reasonably performance minded, if you find yourself running into performance issues. If you don't have performance issues, then don't worry about it and don't do anything until you run into performance issues. They're easy to solve when you have them, trying to solve them before you have them is not a good idea.

There's a hundred things you can do, but they all depend on your specific application.

1. If you don't need to know the values before you submit the form, don't even store them in state, just get them in your `onSubmit` function by using DOM APIs or React refs
2. A really easy way to minimize rerenders is to use `onBlur` instead of `onChange` and update your state after the user tabs away from the input. This works if it suits your applications UI requirements
3. Anything more fine-grained than that and you should be leaning into a highly-tuned form library like [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) and learn how to use it. It's exceptional at what it does, but every library comes with a learning curve and you should be prepared to invest a little time into learning how to use it properly.

Of course, if you are not experiencing any performance problems right now, but are worried about performance in the future, [I would urge you to not do anything until you actually have a problem](https://stackify.com/premature-optimization-evil/)